# Using Excel on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, excel, azure, cloud

I am trying to create excel files on Azure using Excel interop but I get the following message:

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154"

I understood I must have excel on the server to solve this issue.

Does anyone knows how do I install excel on azure?

Thank you, Ido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need Excel on the server and I imagine it would be quite difficult to get it to install on a Azure WebRole. Generally using Office automation on a server like this is a bad idea, and not supported by Microsoft. You would be best off using something like SpreadsheetGear (http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) which doesn't require Excel installed and will be much more stable and performant.

Comment: Even with VM roles I wouldn't recommend it. Server side automation is just not stable.

Comment: Thanks, But do you know any free solution?